# Find oldest to youngest record Python

Tags: python, function, date, max, min

I am trying to retrieve data from the first available date to present date from an API. I've tried using `min` and `max` in parameter.

```
def getcomplete(cid, pid, tag, type):
    api_endpoint = ''

    headers = {'token': get_token()['access_token'], 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

    params = {'cid': str(cid),
              'from-date': datetime.datetime.min,
              'to-date': datetime.datetime.max,
              'tag': str(tag),
              'type': str(type),
              'pid': str(pid)
              }

    r = requests.post(url=api_endpoint, headers=headers, params=params)

    return r.json()

getcomplete(10,12,'x','y')
```

This returns {'status': 'success', 'message': 'success', 'data': []}.

Is there anything wrong with the written function.

Thanks

Comment: "this returns min() arg is an empty sequence. This makes sense because I'm not passing anything while calling the function.

How should I fix it?" → Pass something into the function?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm leaving it blank I want to get the oldest record.  Thanks

Comment: What did you expect to be the result of "min(<empty string>)"?

Comment: Why are you using `min` and `max` *at all*?

Comment: using *min* and *max* to get the oldest(from_date) and youngest(to_date) . Thanks.

Comment: Edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Pythons `min()` and `max()` have an optional `default` parameter. This will prevent them from throwing errors

```py
min("", default="")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It didn't work. I've edited the question.

Comment: Have you tried using `datetime.datetime.min` and `datetime.datetime.max` as the default values. Also why would you expect an iterable for a from/to date. Seems like you would just want to use the value passed in.

Comment: I've tried hardcoding the values as  *datetime.datetime.min* & *datetime.datetime.max* but it gave blank output * {'status': 'success', 'message': 'success', 'data': []}.*